# Insert Array and Non-Array Variables from Checkbox List

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to code a simple grocery list web app for my family to use where the user would check the items they want to add to their list and then have it added to a table for future retrieval.  But I am running into trouble while trying to insert an array along with the username into a MySQL database.  I've searched around for an answer, but cannot find one that satisfies the following:

1. Inserts both an array and a non-array.
2. Does not use deprecated mysql_ functions.

Ideally, I would love to use PDO since I have some other queries using PDO.  I know the array is being passed because I print it out successfully on the page on which I wish to execute the query.  Below is what I have so far.

HTML Form (the checkbox values are populated from another MySQL table):

```
<div class="ui-body">
<? while($row = $resultRedMeat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo '<label><input type="checkbox" id="groceryListItem[]" name="groceryListItem[]" value="'.$row['food'].'">'.$row['food'].'</label>';
}?>
</div>
```

PHP Code to Insert

```
$groceryListItems = $_POST['groceryListItem'];    
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `grocerylist` 
                         SET `username` = $username, `food` = ?");
foreach((array)$groceryListItems as $groceryListItem){
            $q ->execute($username, array($groceryListItem['groceryListItem']));
            }
```

The errors I get in my error log are:

1. PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'groceryListItem'
2. PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 parameter, 2 given

While all the values being passed are from a database and there is no user entry, if you guys think it is still good to protect against injection, I wouldn't mind some advice on that, too, in this context.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.

Your `$groceryListItems` isn't structured the way you think. Use `print_r($groceryListItems)` to view the array and figure out how you can access the element you want.

*Re. Your Comment:*

```
print_r($grocery_list_items);
Array ( [0] => Ground Beef (Extra Lean),
        [1] => Flank Steak,
        [2] => Roast )
```

If you loop through this array;

```
$foreach( $grocery_list_items as $key=>$value ){
    //$key will be 0 then 1 the 2
    //$value will be Ground Beef (Extra Lean) then Flank Steak then Roast
}
```

In your query you have `SET username = $username` but leter you try to pass username as a paramter. Replace `$username` with `?`

`PDO::execute`expects a single argument that is an array of paramters to pass to the query. [Read me](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
So combine $username and the greoceryitem into one array to pass to execute.

Also, your query is mixing UPDATE and INSERT syntax.
If you are trying to run an INSERT query it should be;

```
INSERT INTO `grocerylist` (`username`,`food`) VALUES (?,?);
```

Comment: Ugh.  Embarrassed about my SQL statement  Apologies for that.  The array looks like this:  Array ( [0] => Ground Beef (Extra Lean) [1] => Flank Steak [2] => Roast ).  I'm not really sure what I expect it to look like, to be honest.  This one of my first go arounds with arrays.  
So for the PDO statement, it looks like I need to create an array from $username and my existing array of $groceryListItems?

Comment: See my comment. It should help. basically once you are in the foreach loop, grocery_list_item is just a string.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  With it, I arrived at the following, which works:

$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `grocerylist` (`username`,`food`) VALUES (?,?)");

foreach ($groceryListItems as $key=>$groceryListItem){
 $listInsert = array($username, $groceryListItem);
 $q -> execute ($listInsert);
 }